# How to compile Node.js addons without using node-gyp?

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

How to compile Node.js addons without using node-gyp?

For an example: `gcc -shared addon.cc -I/usr/include/nodejs/deps/v8/include` (maybe it doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

NAPI is a set of [ABI stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) functions, include the `node_api.h`
the crux of the matter. And here we want to use [node-addon-api (c++)](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api), certainly, you can use only C.

I make a template repo, so `git clone https://github.com/kkocdko/hinapi`.

On Linux, you need to place all deps correctly and run:

```bash
g++ src/main.cc -o build/main.node \
  -I third_party/node-addon-api \
  -I third_party/node-api-headers/include \
  -shared -fPIC
```

And there's my [blog post](https://kkocdko.site/post/202303261531) which solve this question with some extra infomations.